# Error upon importing SVN repo to GitHub using wizard

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn

I am using the GitHub [import wizard](https://import.github.com/new) to import a number of SVN repos. However, it fails for specific repos (in about 80% of my repos it works, though, so it's not me using it wrong).

I get two different error types, each occuring for specific SVN repos (i.e. they are not happening randomly):

1. Right at the start of the import, the error says

   > There was an error mapping commits
2. The import drags on for a while up to 100%. Once it enters the "Optimizing repository and pushing commits to GitHub..." phase, it fails after some time with the error

   > There was an error pushing commits to GitHub.

Are these structural problems in the SVN repos? What do I need to look out for to change this?

Comment: You could try migrating it locally and then pushing to GitHub or wherever: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git#Subversion

Answer (score 0):

do a git svn clone of the svn repository and then import that git repo

```
git svn clone http://mySVN/repo/repoFolder
(leave away the repoFolder depending on your repo-structure)
```